# C# Using Two Collections That Contain The Same Data

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I'm fairly new to C#. In C++ if I wanted two collections that contained some or all of the same data it's really easy. For example, you just create the objects on the heap and use a collection of (auto) pointers in each collection. C# doesn't seem to have a concept of pointers so how do you do the same thing in C#?

One collection (proabably an array) will contain all objects. The other (probably a queue) will contain a subset of what is in the array. Eventually the objects will be removed from the queue but remain in the array.

This, I am sure, is a really simple question but I'm still getting my head around the differences between C++ and C#.

Comment: @harryovers only in unsafe mode.

Comment: ... but generally you don't need to use them.

Comment: references works as pointers in C# (in this context)

Comment: @Abdul Muqtadir yes you are right i was just noting that "C# doesn't seem to have a concept of pointers..." was an in correct statement.

Comment: Thanks. This is where my mindset needs to change. I am used to things in C++ being passed by value by default. Understanding that C# passes by reference helps me see how to achieve what I want. I'm still a bit confused as to how C# manages the lifetime of the objects. I am assuming there is some sort of automatic reference counting under the hood. Otherwise how does it know to not delete the object when I remove it from the queue but knows to delete it if I also remove it from the array. Is this where the automatic garbage collection of C# comes in?

Comment: Yes I know you can put pointers in unmanaged (unsafe) C# but I am trying to avoid that. So yes my statement wasn't totally correct. Sorry.

Comment: As I noted in my answer, there is a garbage collector that keeps track of reference counters and object life time and automatically tries to clean orphaned objects on the heap when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# has pointers in an unsafe context as you're used to in C++. However, most complex objects are passed by reference in C# to begin with, meaning (simplified) that a single object you add to two collections will be the same object. Strings and integers, among others, will be value types and strings, for instance, will be immutable.

More on types in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ewxz6et.aspx

Lengthy blogpost on immutability: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx

---

C# has a garbage collector that takes care of memory and reference management for you, and any orphaned references will usually be cleaned up within a reasonable amount of time.

More on memory management: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for that. I understand it now and actually now I do understand it I realise what a stupid question it was. So thanks for everyone's patience.

Comment: Not stupid at all, for someone going from unmanaged to managed code.

Answer (score 2):

May be you need to understand reference and value types first.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Types.aspx

Comment: I understand that. It isn't new to C#. However, in C++ using references in collections is best avoided in my experience. There were situations where things got messy and collections were largely unusable when using references. Are references any different in C# to how they are in C++? A List of object references in C++ would be horrible. Does C# automatically do some sort of reference counting?

Comment: C# has a garbage collector that takes care of memory and reference management for you, and any orphaned references will usually be cleaned up within a reasonable amount of time. Updated my answer to include this tidbit. =)

Answer (score 0):

In C# data is by default [referenced](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) (not copied, unless it is a [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) (ValueType)), so if you assign a variable in one place with another object it is a reference which is created.

Example:

```
class C {}
var a = new C();
var b = a;
//a and b points to the same object
```

Anyways you can use pointer in C# in an [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx) context (though not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

Almost all objects in C# are constructed on the heap, and are accessed via pointers. The `.` is used almost like `->` in C++. IMHO its just works more naturally.

When thinking about the "pointers", a collection doesn't contain data, it references data.

So in your example, it will just work as you described it.